# Light (Laser) operated optical switch

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, quantum-information, laser, quantum-optics

I have searched the web and found that optical switches are activated either through mechanical or electro/magnetics. Making them sort of Optomechanical or optoelectronic switches.

Lets exclude electromagnetically induced transparent switches. Are there other solid state based optical switches at are fully operated using lasers only?

I would be grateful if you could include link and/or references.

**UPDATE**

The **optical switches** I am after typically receives a laser at point **A** then output it at point **B**, when it is activated via electrical means (or magnetic), it cuts the signal output to point **B**. So instead of being switched on and off by electric or magnetic means, are there **solid state based optical switches**  that are switched on and off by Laser?

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to switch the laser on/off via some signal or are trying to use the laser to switch something else on/off, such as the current in a circuit?

Comment: Ok, I have now updated my query. :)

Comment: Saturable absorbers - do they suit your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sum-frequency system with a "hot" mirror could act something like an optical switch:

[image]

Unlike a switch, the output frequency will be different from either of the inputs.

**Edit:** For an example of sum-frequency generation crystals see:

[Thorlabs Introduction To Periodically Poled Lithium Niobate (PPLN) (PDF)](https://www.thorlabs.com/catalogpages/693.pdf)

Thorlabs also sells hot mirrors.

Comment: I would like to ask more about a specific materials used for summing crystal and "hot" mirror.

Answer (score 1):

An acousto-optical modulator can act as an optical switch, with the switching controlled by the application of radiofrequency power. An AOM operates by setting up a compression wave in a crystal from which the light diffracts. Light which is diffracted into at least the first order can then be used for whatever you like.

However, there are some caveats -- it's not possible to diffract 100% of the light into one of the orders -- 40-50% would be quite good. When the switch is "off", there is still a small amount of power that leaks through, and the AOM also shifts the frequency of the laser by a small amount (the RF frequency).

[1] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousto-optic_modulator

[2] - https://www.rp-photonics.com/acousto_optic_modulators.html